# Visual Studio run custom build tool when dependencies change

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, swig

I have a solution with two C++ projects in Visual Studio 2013.

Project A creates a static library.  Project B produces a SWIG-generated DLL wrapper for A, linking the lib generated by A.  The complicating factor is that B generates code using a "Custom Build Step", set to execute before ClCompile. The custom build step calls out to an external tool to generate wrapper code based on classes defined in header files in project A.  If the generation completes successfully, project B builds a DLL from the generated code, linking against the .lib generated in project A.

The problem I have is that the custom step in B is occurring on every build (as one would expect), but I'd like to make it happen when there are changes to header files in A.  I can't see a way of defining a rule that enforces this condition.  If I add "..\project A*.h" to the Additional Dependencies field of the Custom Build Step, the missing link would be a macro that evaluates to true when any file in Additional Dependencies is newer than any file in the Outputs field.

Does Visual Studio provide a macro that tells me when the Custom Build Step's Additional Dependencies are newer than Outputs, or am I in scripting territory here?

Answer (score 1):

I use a custom build similar to this:

```
<CustomBuild>
  <Command>swig -c++ -python -I..\include -outdir $(OutDir) %(Identity)</Command>
  <Message>Creating SWIG-generated files...</Message>
  <Outputs>$(ProjectName)_wrap.cxx;$(Outdir)$(ProjectName).py</Outputs>
  <AdditionalInputs>header1.h;header2.h;header3.h</AdditionalInputs>
</CustomBuild>
```

I don't use anything additional, so Visual Studio seems to have a default rule to run the custom build step if files in AdditionalInputs are newer than Outputs.

Comment: *so Visual Studio seems to have a default rule* it does, CustomBuild inputs/outputs are treated similar to e.g. compiler inputs/outputs in that they have an entry in the file tracker mechanism etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried Custom Build instead of Custom Build Step (I can confirm the XML is essentially the same as your example above), but unfortunately it just doesn't seem to work. I've tried defining additional inputs with every combination of relative and absolute paths, and with/without wildcards, all without success. The timestamp of the additional inputs file is definitely more recent than any of the outputs. I'll take the hit on having SWIG run the generation every time - better than having the build fail when I change interfaces and don't force a rebuild.